GitLab mirroring push issue
I suffering trouble on gitLab some repository mirroring.
I'm hosting GitLab site as docker container and mirroring it's repositories another gitLab site.
After committing big size images, this problem was started
Error message is
"
13:push to mirror: git push: exit status 1, stderr: "error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Broken pipe\nsend-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet\nfatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly\nEverything up-to-date\n".
"
So I've tried size up http postBuffer on my gitLab container but I was failed because I couldn't find .git/config files.
how can I fix this problem?
Please, check my issue.
